# Out of memory when trying to get drawable resources from other apps

Tags: android, out-of-memory, drawable, android-resources

From my app I am trying to get from other installed apps a specific drawable resources. The resource always exist. I use :

```
Resources resources = activity.getPackageManager().getResourcesForApplication(packageName);
int previewResID = resources.getIdentifier("image", "drawable", packageName);
Drawable myThemePreview = resources.getDrawable(previewResID);
```

I get the out of memory on the last line before drawable converted to bitmap and shows up to user

Comment: Can you post a bit more of your code ? It's hard to tell what's wrong with so few lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [BitmapFactory::decodeResource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) using with a BitmapFactory.Options with a specified [inSampleSize](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize) to reduce memory.

It would look something like this:

```
Resources resources = activity.getPackageManager().getResourcesForApplication(packageName);
int previewResID = resources.getIdentifier("image", "drawable", packageName);
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 4;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources,previewResId,options);
```

Comment: You can also use options.inJustDecodeBounds=true to have the BitmapFactory retrieve the width and height of the target bitmap and use those to calculate inSampleSize.